# MS Access how set focus on a particular multiple report instance

Tags: ms-access, report, multiple-instances, setfocus

My problem is to set the focus on a  particular Report instance opened . I copy a function which works perfectly for form object but not for Report object. My function:

```vb
Function mInstanceReportCA(varYear As Variant)

Dim oReport As Access.Report
Dim obj As Object

' Création du nouveau formulaire
For Each obj In clsReport
    If obj.txtYear = varYear Then
        obj.Visible 'Error 438 
        obj.SetFocus 'Error 2465
        Exit Function
    End If
Next obj

Set oReport = New Report_rptCaMois

' Activation du nouveau formulaire
With oReport

    If varYear = "1999" Then
        .txtYear = "1999"
        .Caption = "Rapport toutes années confondues"
        .Filter = "Year(dateFacture) > 1999 "
    Else
        .txtYear = CStr(varYear)
        .Caption = "Rapport pour l'année  " & CStr(varYear)
        .Filter = "Year(dateFacture) = " & varYear
    End If
    .FilterOn = True
    .Visible = True
End With


' Ajout du formulaire à la collection globale
clsReport.Add Item:=oReport, Key:=CStr(oReport.Hwnd)

Set oReport = Nothing
end function
```

In the  ***For Each obj In clsReport*** routine, commands below generate error messages

1. obj.Visible :  Error 438
2. obj.SetFocus : Error 2465

thanks for your help

Comment: What is clsReport? Seems not to be an array of report.objects

Comment: clsReport is a collection object

Comment: check with `debug.print TypeName(obj)` if its a report object.

Comment: A report can't get focus, just its controls. If you want to bring it to front you can use `DoCmd.SelectObject acReport, obj.name`

Answer (score 1):

The solution

In general part module :

```
Public Declare Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
```

In the block code :

```
BringWindowToTop obj.hwnd
```

Thanks to [Dirk Goldgar](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bb99080e-bc9f-4c0e-8200-6f75956377b3/multiple-opened-report-instances-how-to-set-focus-on-particular-opened-instance?forum=accessdev#0ca9c8b7-64c0-4751-a931-471c42d9679a)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this worked for forms but I see 2 possible reasons why this doesn't work.

You declare obj as Object.  That is a generic data type that does not have any properties until it is instantized (Set obj = New Report).  It may work if you reference with the bang (!) obj.txtdate / obj!visible / obj!Setfocus via late binding.

Also object.visible needs to be assigned a value (True/False).  Unless you are dealing with multiple types of objects I would Dim obj as Access.Report.

Comment: You're right for object.visible, it needs to be assigned with true/false value. I corrected my code and now no more error message. But for obj.setFocus, still the error message "Run-time error 2465 - Application-defined or Object-defined error"

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, clsReport is not a collection, its a Dictionary object.  When you set oReport = Nothing you are taking it out of scope since the dictionary does not keep a copy of the object, only a reference to it.

Collections store a full copy, which is why dictionaries are so much faster and less bloated when storing complex objects.

Again, why it worked for forms I don't know, you might not have been making copies of the forms like you do reports.

If you're not sure put this line before ' Création du nouveau formulaire

```
Msgbox Typename(clsReport)
```

If it says Dictionary there is your answer, when you destroy the object (oReport), the reference in the Dictionary points to nothing.  It does not remove the Dictionary item which is why you don't get an error when you reference the collection(dictionary) item in the For Each loop, only when you try to access the objects properties, which no longer exist.

Put the same Msgbox line above obj.Visible

```
Msgbox TypeName(obj)
```

and it should come back "Empty".

Comment: On VBA editor spy window,  I checked if obj and it is well instantiated. No problem with it. Another proof, the test  'If obj.txtYear = varYear Then' works perfectly

Comment: I think we need to see more of the code.  Can you post the actual form code and the collection declaration?